# Reading a file into a binary array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, binary, char, unsigned

I have got a file that contains data for multiple jpegs (along with some garbage), i need to extract binary from this file, filter out the garbage and create jpegs. I know the starting binary sequence of the jpegs.

```
char buffer[30];
ifstream fin;
fin.open ("FILENAME.raw", ios::in | ios::binary);
while (!fin.eof())
{
    fin.read(buffer,30);
    cout<<buffer[2]<<endl;
}
fin.close();
```

Here i am trying to print the file in binary but, when i run this code, alien characters are printed on the screen.

Comment: Probably you have alien characters in your file. That's usually the case with binary data.

Comment: What's the contents of the file itself as well?

Comment: Seems everything's fine and you have no problem. And in fact you didn't ask a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think problem here was "cout << buffer[2]" which was converting your binary information to charecters. Try int cast before , also you should use a static "unsigned char array"
because binary data can be unsigned .That will work :

```
unsigned char buffer[ 30 ];
ifstream fin;
fin.open ("FILENAME.raw", ios::in | ios::binary);
while (!fin.eof())
{

    fin.read( (char*)( &buffer[0] ), 30 ) ;
    cout << (int)buffer[2] << " ";
}
fin.close();
return 0;
```

Also if you want to traverse the binary why you are just printing buffer[2].

Answer (score 1):

You should double check the binary contents of the file, as your code seems perfectly fine.